# can't build or test kubernetes on docker or locally

Tags: kubernetes

I cloned the `kubernetes` repo and installed all the required packages to my mac but whenever I run `build/run.sh make all` or `build/run.sh test` I'm getting the following error:

```
Call stack:
  1: /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:857 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
  2: hack/make-rules/build.sh:27 main(...)
Exiting with status 1
make: *** [Makefile:93: all] Error 1
!!! [0120 11:32:00] Call tree:
!!! [0120 11:32:00]  1: build/../build/common.sh:523 kube::build::run_build_command_ex(...)
!!! [0120 11:32:00]  2: build/run.sh:39 kube::build::run_build_command(...)
!!! Error in build/../build/common.sh:598
  Error in build/../build/common.sh:598. '"${docker_cmd[@]}" "${cmd[@]}"' exited with status 2
Call stack:
  1: build/../build/common.sh:598 kube::build::run_build_command_ex(...)
  2: build/../build/common.sh:523 kube::build::run_build_command(...)
  3: build/run.sh:39 main(...)
Exiting with status 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: what is your go version?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu `go version go1.13.6 darwin/amd64`

Answer (score 1):

Support for building kubernetes using go version 1.13 is under [work](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82531)
Try with go version above 1.12.9 but less than 1.13.

Comment: I downgraded to version `1.12.15` and it still fails. I can see this line in the logs when running `test`: `Go version: go version go1.13.6 linux/amd64`. don't know how is it possible since `go version` shows `1.12.15` for me and I removed the previous version